# Insert Mulitple Row Data from Jtable into database

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to save Multiple row data from JTable into Database, Here is my code for reference:

```
try{

int rows=tblCO2.getRowCount();

for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
{
    String coitemname = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String cocateg = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 1);
    String codesc = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 2);
    String coloc = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 3);
    String coitemtagno = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 4);
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iotams",user,pass);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        String queryco = "Insert into tblcheckout(CheckoutID,ItemTagNo,ItemName,Category,Description,Location) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);

        pst.setString(1, coitemname);
        pst.setString(2, cocateg);
        pst.setString(3, codesc);
        pst.setString(4, coloc);
        pst.setString(5, coitemtagno);

        pst.addBatch();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
pst.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```

The Problem is, it is only inserting one row data into database. Can someone please help me? :( thanks!

Comment: Don't recreate the connection (or the `PrepearedStatement` I think) on each loop.  Instead, create them once and simply keep call `PreaparedStatement#setXxx` and `PrepearedStatement#addBatch` in the loop and finally, call `executeBatch`

Comment: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) was made (probably not really) for JDBC resource management, it makes it so easy to manage the various levels of statements and objects which need to close when you're done with them

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks.  I'll edit my Code and Update my post once done.

Comment: I wonder how it makes sense to edit the _question_ to contain the _answer_ ... in other words: don't do that. Keep the question as it is and accept the correct answer.

Comment: @Tom sorry, and thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove following line codes from loop and place before loop

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iotams",user,pass);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
String queryco = "Insert into tblcheckout(CheckoutID,ItemTagNo,ItemName,Category,Description,Location) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
```

**Example:** Replace your code by following code

```
try{

int rows=tblCO2.getRowCount();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iotams",user,pass);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

String queryco = "Insert into tblcheckout(CheckoutID,ItemTagNo,ItemName,Category,Description,Location) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
{
    String coitemname = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String cocateg = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 1);
    String codesc = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 2);
    String coloc = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 3);
    String coitemtagno = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 4);
    pst.setString(1, coitemname);
    pst.setString(2, cocateg);
    pst.setString(3, codesc);
    pst.setString(4, coloc);
    pst.setString(5, coitemtagno);

    pst.addBatch();
}
pst.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```

Then run it think it work.

For Batch insert example is here https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/14878.htm

Comment: It works but sometimes it put in the duplicates and sometimes it does not insert in the last row

Answer (score 0):

the code above is not able to run in netbeans ,
However I made a version for netbeans.

```
try{

  int rows=jTable1.getRowCount();

  for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
  {   
    Integer qty = (Integer)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
    Double unitprice = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
    String description = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
    Double total = (Double)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);
    String queryco = "Insert into invoice(qty,unitprice,description,total) values ('"+qty+"','"+unitprice+"','"+description+"','"+total+"')";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
    pst.execute();     
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Save");
}
catch(Exception e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```