# Insert correctly data into a MySQL table from JTable in Java NetBeans?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

Sorry for the bad english, i'm not a native speaker.

I'm making an administration system, in wich i need to add a ticket form (attached image), that form fill three MySQL tables, the table should send the data depending on the selected item of the combobox, between "Entrada" and "Salida".

The user fill the jtable. When the selected item is "Entrada", the jtable fill the field "ITEM" in the database, and when is "Salida", the filled field should be "Codigo de producto".

I hope someone could help me, i'm getting crazy with this
The code of the method that send the data is the following:

```
public void llenarventa_compra(String tiponota, String folio){

    Connection cn=con.conexion();

    try{

        String a = null;
        String b = null;               
        String c = null;

        int i=0;     

        do{

            if(tiponota.equals("Entrada")==true){

                b= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,1);
                c= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,2);
                String d= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,3);
                String f= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,4);
                i++;
                PreparedStatement pst=cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO venta_compra (Folio,ITEM,Cantidad,lote_i,lote_f) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

                pst.setString(1, folio);
                pst.setString(2, b);
                pst.setString(3, c);
                pst.setString(4, d);
                pst.setString(5, f);

            }

            if(tiponota.equals("Salida")==true){

                a= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,0);
                c= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,2);
                String d= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,3);
                String f= (String)Tabla_P.getValueAt(i,4);
                i++;

                PreparedStatement pst=cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO venta_compra (Folio,Codigo_productos,Cantidad,lote_i,lote_f) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

                pst.setString(1, folio);
                pst.setString(2, a);
                pst.setString(3, c);
                pst.setString(4, d);
                pst.setString(5, f);

            }

        }while (c.equals(" ")==false);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos venta_compra guardados con exito");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8NVm.jpg

Comment: No need to apologize for not being a native speaker, few persons are on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Mulitple Row Data from Jtable into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755997/insert-mulitple-row-data-from-jtable-into-database)

Comment: `if(tiponota.equals("Salida")==true)` ... you dont need the `==true` part, because when tipnota already equals "Salida", the `if()` becomes true.