# Is there a way how i can save severals of table data to mysql

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have a table in Java where it contains several rows but when I save the data only the last row is saved the rest is not saved.

Below is my code:

```
try {
    int rows=jTable1.getRowCount();
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        String qtys = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
        String name = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
        String commo = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
        String wei = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);

        String queryco = "Insert into invoice(qtys,name,commo,wei) " +
                         "values ('"+qtys +"','"+name+"','"+commo+"','"+wei+"')";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
        pst.execute();     
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Save");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can someone help to sort out the above problem

Comment: Hi @janes, this link might help you "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755997/insert-mulitple-row-data-from-jtable-into-database". Look like same intention.

Comment: @Pearl i tried it out but still not all are saved

Comment: could you please provide the source file. So, i can try in my local

Comment: how many rows currently your table consists of?

Comment: Did you try with batch insert?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;



public class JTableExample {

JFrame f; 
// Table 
JTable j; 


void process()  throws Exception
{ 
    // Frame initiallization 
    f = new JFrame(); 

    // Frame Title 
    f.setTitle("JTable Example"); 

    // Initializing the JTable 
    j = new JTable(); 
    j.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300); 

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);

    // add header of the table
    String header[] = new String[] { "Prority", "Task Title", "Start",
    };

    // add header in table model     
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);

    for (int count = 1; count <= 1000; count++) {
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] { "data"+count, "data"+count, "data"+count});
    }

    j.setModel(dtm);


    // adding it to JScrollPane 
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j); 
    f.add(sp); 
    // Frame Size 
    f.setSize(500, 200); 
    // Frame Visible = true 
    f.setVisible(true); 

    int rows=j.getRowCount();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection connection = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila",
    "root","root");

    String sqlQuery = "Insert into sakila.student(name,dep,rollnumber) 
    values(?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement  stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    try {
        for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
        {   
            System.out.println("Count:"+row);
            stmt.clearParameters();
            String name= (String) j.getValueAt(row, 0);
            String rollNumber = (String) j.getValueAt(row, 1);
            String dep = (String) j.getValueAt(row, 2);

            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setString(2, dep);
            stmt.setString(3, rollNumber);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    connection.close();
} 

// Driver  method 
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception
{   
    JTableExample jt = new JTableExample(); 
    jt.process();
} }
```

I have used this code where i can store 5000 rows to the database without any issue. All the data are stored successfully in the database.

Comment: Optimalisation: the variable `sqlQuery` and `stmt` can be created before the `for` loop. This way the stmt is prepared only once and you only need to call setters and executeUpdate(). Additionally, to make sure all parameters are set correctly you can call stmt.clearParameters() at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: Can you explain what the OP was doing wrong, and how do you solve this ?

Comment: @vincrichaud, i didn't get you? Janes not shared any source code. The above code snippet which is able to insert the data nearly 5000 record. I didn't test more than that.